# VBA: incrementing a number stored in a string while preserving it's formatting

Tags: vba, string, format

In a VBA macro that I'm writing, I need to increment a number that is stored in a String variable, for example "1", "01", "001", etc. It can also be "010", "000123", and so on. I am aware of the Format call that can turn incremented number, for example "2" into "002" with Format(2, "00#"), but I don't know how to first read the format of the original number to store it's format and re-apply it after the increment. The only way I can think of is counting trailing zeroes, but isn't there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will preserve leading zeros:

```
Function IncrementNumberLeadingZeros(sVal As String, Change As Long) As String
    
    Dim L As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim Frmt As String
    
    L = Len(sVal)
    For I = 1 To L
        Frmt = Frmt & "0"
    Next I
    
    IncrementNumberLeadingZeros = Format(CLng(sVal) + Change, Frmt)
    
End Function
```

I tested like this:

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print IncrementNumberLeadingZeros("00210", 1)
End Sub
```

Output Was:

[image]

**OR, even shorter with a little help for our friends:**

```
Function IncrementNumberLeadingZeros(sVal As String, Change As Long) As String
   IncrementNumberLeadingZeros = Format$(CLng(sVal) + Change, String(Len(sVal), "0"))
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was writing a very similar thing, but you did it much better.

Comment: Oh wow, I was looking up how to make a string of n zeros, and couldn't find anything faster than I could type a for loop. I could have used this tons of time in the past. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Great addition, @BigBen. Respect.